# Controlling underfloor electrical heating

Tags: heating

What is the most cost effective form of controlling the electricity use whilst still having toastie warm feet on the tile floors? We currently have underfloor electrical heating on room air temperature thermostat. Would it help to program on/off times if possible?

Comment: Is the underfloor heating the only heat source?

Comment: No, we also have a free standing wood burner in family room, this is only burning in evenings

Comment: Reducing temperature. For a given temperature, you require N kWh of electrical energy. There's no magical bullet.